# Need Optimized Query which take data from three tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Three tables

```
accounts, products, users
```

1. Select users id and email from users table where there id are in
   accounts
2. Then filter them out from products table where user
   bought more than 3 products
   (Need to count users in product table and exclude a user if his count is more than 3).

   ```
      SELECT id, email
   FROM  users 
   WHERE id
   IN (
   SELECT user_id
   FROM accounts
   WHERE users.id = user_id
   )
   ```

I got all users id and emails, but now I need to filter them out from product table. In product table I have 'product_id' and 'leader_id', which is user id.

I need optimized query, because tables are very big

Comment: Not enough info.  We don't know how the tables relate. We don't know if any indexes exist on the tables to improve performance and we don't know what you tried.

Comment: Exactly....show us some sample data or your table structures ;)

Comment: @javier that's a pretty big leap.  your assuming each table has a field called ID, where as I infer it to mean their Primary key which could be Account_ID, Product_ID, User_ID or perhaps, just 'ID',  The ambiguity is why I asked.

Comment: users table: columns are, id and email. accounts table:  id and user_id. and in product table columns: id, product_id and leader_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand a bit...something like this should works:

```
 select u.id,u.mail,
 (select count(1) 
   from products
  where products.leader_id = u.id)
 as conteo
 from user u
  left join account ac
 on(u.id = ac.user_id)
 having (conteo>3)
```

I hope it helps ;)

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an aoptimized query then please provide proper details of your schema - the tables, the data types and the indexes.

```
   SELECT id, email
   FROM  users 
   WHERE id
   IN (
      SELECT user_id
      FROM accounts
      WHERE users.id = user_id
   )
```

Never use sub-queries unless you absolutely have to. Since you don't want any of the data in the accounts table, an 'EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounts WHERE users.id=user_id)' would be a lot more efficient in most DBMS - but NOT in MySQL which doesn't optimize push predicates well.

Query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.email
FROM users u INNER JOIN accounts a 
ON u.id=a.user_id;
```

> out from products table where user bought more than 3 products

While I can guess enough of the schema to re-write your previous query, I have no idea how the products table is structured, indeed, 'products' implies a catalog of items, and the relationship to accounts seems to be an n:m implying that there would have to be a missing table decomposing the relationship. Further, from your description the account data is independent of the "product" table data (which seems vry odd). Do you want to include cases where the user has no related records in "product"?

Assuming this is not the case, and guessing as to what the structure might be....

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, SUM(IF(leader_id IS NULL, 0, amount))
FROM users u INNER JOIN accounts a 
ON u.id=a.user_id
LEFT JOIN product p
ON u.id=p.leader_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.email;
```

> I need optimized query, because tables are very big

Why do you need to look at all your data in a single query?

Comment: Good query, but users are not excluded those who bought more than 3 times. Where there id is in products in the column leader_id. I need to exclude all those users who bought products more than 3 times

Comment: Whoops - got a bit lost in the story - add 'HAVING SUM(IF(leader_id IS NULL, 0, amount)) < 4' at the end.